# NullPointerException after clicking login button in android

Tags: java, php, android

I am creating a login page and validating username and password using php,when i click on login button after entering username and password getting  app has stopped unexpectedly and NullPointerException,have attached my code please any one tell me what mistake i have done.

Thank you.
mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.validation;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button login;
    String name="",pass="";
    byte[] data;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    InputStream inputStream;
    SharedPreferences app_preferences ;
    CheckBox check;
    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check);

        String Str_user = app_preferences.getString("username","0" );
        String Str_pass = app_preferences.getString("password", "0");
        String Str_check = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
        if(Str_check.equals("yes"))
        {
                username.setText(Str_user);
                password.setText(Str_pass);
                check.setChecked(true);
        }   
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                name = username.getText().toString();
                pass = password.getText().toString();
                String Str_check2 = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
                if(Str_check2.equals("yes"))
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", name);
                    editor.putString("password", pass);
                     editor.commit();
                }
                if(name.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
                {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blank Field..Please Enter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {


                try {
                    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Purchase Order/userlogin.php");
                    // Add your data
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserEmail", name.trim()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pass.trim()));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    data = new byte[256];

                    buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int len = 0;
                    while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                    {
                        buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                    }

                    inputStream.close();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
            }
        });
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                {


                     editor.putString("checked", "yes");
                     editor.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                     editor.putString("checked", "no");
                     editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }      

    public void sendMessage(View view) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mainpage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:onClick="sendMessage"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textview"
       android:text="login" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
       android:ems="10"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:hint="Enter Name"
       android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
       android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="Password"
       android:inputType="textPassword"
       android:textColorHint="#ffff299f" />

   <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/check"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button"
       android:text="Remember me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

userlogin.php

```
<?php 
require_once('Purchase Order/dao/connectDB'); 
mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$localhost);

$username = $_POST['UserEmail'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

 $query_search = "select * from user_login where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
 $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);

 if($rows --> 0) { 
 echo "Y"; 
 }
else  {
echo "N"; 
}
?>
```

LogCat:

```
06-03 17:56:38.044: D/AndroidRuntime(416): Shutting down VM
06-03 17:56:38.044: W/dalvikvm(416): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.example.validation.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-03 17:56:38.063: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace you get?

Comment: post logcat so we can suggest solution

Comment: You can not perform Network Operation on Main Thread. So it might be NetworkOnMainThreadException not NullPointerException.

Comment: ho i have attached LogCat please tell me how to solve this...

Comment: one thing I see is, that You gave a method to onClick in Your xml attribute, but also set the button onClickListener....don´t do this, use only one.

Comment: It seems you have not added permission for internet in your manifest file.After adding permission you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: To resolve NetworkOnMainThreadException exception you have to perform network operation in worker thread either AsynkTask or Thread.

Comment: Which line is line 110 of MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the following line is at line 110 of your file. *(But lines have shifted after you posted the source code, I think)*

```
if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
```

The `NullPointerException` means that the buffer is still `null` when this point is reached.

To fix this bug quickly, change it to this:

```
if((buffer != null) && buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
```

Comment: hi,Thank you ur code is working but getting NullPointerException on emulator after clicking login button.

Comment: The line number is specified in the stacktrace of the exception. NPE always means that you are calling a method on an unassigned (null) variable.